# Push notification work when app installed via XCode but inconsistent when installed via iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode

SUMMARY: 
Push notifications *always* work perfectly if my app is installed via XCode, but if installed via iTunes then they if they work or not depends upon the profiles used to sign the distrubtion. 
BUT some profile combinations which used to work no longer do, and some which didn't now do.

My primary question is which combination of profiles should be used to sign an ad-hoc distrubtion that uses push notifications, and secondary question is why have I observed inconsistency in behavior over time.

DETAILS:
I am developing an app that uses APNs and have been having problems getting the notifications to arrive when the application is distributed as an ad-hoc app and installed via iTunes. The problems are obviously related to it not being signed with the correct profiles but some observations over the past few weeks have left me confused as to what profiles I am supposed to be using to sign the distrubtion.

I had been under the impression that the ad-hoc profile should be used at both phases where signing is required - firstly setting it as the code-signing identiy within XCode as the Archive is being built, and then secondly to sign the distribution. I've been doing it this way and its been working - devices have been able to recieve the push notifications.

Then a few weeks ago the devices stopped receiving push notifications, though there were able to receive them if the build was signed with my development profile and installed via XCode, it was only the ad-hoc distributions that stopped receiving them. After a couple of days of trying everything I eventually deleted the push and ad-hoc profiles and created new ones and everything was working again ... until a couple of days ago when the same thing happened.

I created a new ad-hoc profile again but I still couldn't get the ad-hoc distrubtions to receive the push notifications (though the devices would once again still receive them if the app was installed via XCode). Eventually I changed from signing the distribution with the ad-hoc profile to using the apple push profile and things started working again.
So now I am confused:

```
- am I supposed to sign ad-hoc distrubtions using a) the ad-hoc profile for the archive and then ad-hoc profile again when signing the distribtion of the archive or b) the ad-hoc profile for the archive and the push profile when signing the distribution of the archive?
```

For XCode installations I set the code signing identity to my development profile. For ad-hoc distrubtions I set the code signing identity for the archive to the ad-hoc profile, then at the distrubtion part of the archive sign it again with the ad-hoc OR the push. The OR is there because sometimes one combination works sometimes the other combination works, my whole question therefore is which combination SHOULD it be and why have I observed inconsistency in which combination works and which doesn't.

Thanks

EDIT:
This is a list of the profiles there are, i.e. if I logon to the Apple provisioning portal then click on the provisioning tab then the development tab it lists these:

1) Apple Push Profile - needed to enable APNs

2) NNN Development profile (where NNN is the name of the project)

3) iOS Development profile

4) iOS Team Provisioning Profile

If I click on the provisioning tab then on the distribution tab it lists these:

1) Ad-hoc

In all my extensive searches of books, documentation, forums over a period of many months I have yet to find *definitive* explanation of which combinations of the above should be used under what circumstances *and which take push notifications into consideration*.
A problem is that most documentation and examples do not take push notifications into consideration and this is crucial omission because without the right combination of profiles in the right order the app can install onto the device but push notifications will never be received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after two days trying to figure out what was wrong with the same problem, i found out that when installed via xcode the notifications worked with the development (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com) url. Exporting it as an ipa (ad-hoc) and installing it manually needed notifications to be sent from the production url gateway.push.apple.com (including the production key). So having created both keys, i managed to send notifications with the development url when working on xcode and with the production when installing from exported ipa.

Comment: My question is two years old, and I found out the reason many months ago. I've marked your answer in case people code here for reference.

Comment: Try my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718985/why-my-archive-ipa-file-of-push-notification-app-didnt-work-on-device-instead-o/34725260#34725260. It will 100% work if you set custom provision profile for development APNS at Xcode build setting.

Answer (score 3):

I've had some similar pain.

I response to the following:

> - am I supposed to sign ad-hoc distrubtions using a) the ad-hoc profile for the archive and then ad-hoc profile again when signing the
>     distribtion of the archive or b) the ad-hoc profile for the archive
>     and the push profile when signing the distribution of the archive?

Signing the archive build with ad-hoc or development does not matter. 
What makes all the difference is the signing at the time of the distribution button in Organizer-Archives.

**Sign it with a development provisioning identity. Not ad-hoc.**

I have found signing confusing because there are 2+ places to define signing actions. But in this specific case I've done controlled tests, and sending out ad-hoc distributions, I don't even know if it's possible to get remote notifications into those apps before the app is officially released and can be pushed using the production gateway.

Still, I believe pushing to ad-hoc distributions prior to app-store release should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is possible to get push notifications (there are separate release and test push profiles and servers specifically for this) however it has to be singed at some stage with the push profile otherwise it doesn't work, so this must be factored in at some stage and I'm 99.9% sure signing with a development profile would not enable the pushes to work. (but am unable to check right now).

Comment: The thing I think is causing you and I and others problems is the huge overlap in terms and actions. The term distribution applies to adhoc and app store. For example, "release" is mostly synonymous with distribution, but beyond this, it could be used to refer to a debug build that is packaged for tester installations.  From your question, and comment above, I am not 100% sure what you mean by a push profile, because a push profile could mean either a dev or dist adhoc or dist AppStore. Blah. Not your fault, just too many cross-meaning terms. Plus the differen places to sign stuff, blah.

Comment: By a push profile I mean a provisioning profile which is enabled for push (an ordinary provisioning profile doesn't have this, you have to specifically create one). I've updated my question to append what provisioning profiles I have within the portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a development stage using development application certificate and provisioning you should also generate a development certificate for PUSH notifications that must be installed on the server to authenticate with apple test APNS.
If are in pre production or production stage you should sign you app with distribution certificate and ADHOC or APPSTORE provisioning you should also generate a distribution PUSH certificate that must be installed on the server that communicate with apple's APNS.
I can suggest you to keep an eye on firewalls blocked ports (such a pain also because apple's apns has a wide ip ranges) and pay attention that apple ID's of your application must match the once used for generating push certificates.
Hope this helps,
Andrea

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned pushes ARE working fine and I do not have any problems configuring for or receiving the push messages themselves IF I install via XCode, my question is not about not being able to receive push notifications. I've added a summary to my question.   What do you mean by "..distribution certificate and ADHOC.."? Ad-hoc is a distribution certificate.

Comment: ADHOC and APPSTORE provisioning use distribution certificate so they will match only with PUSH distribution certificate and of course correct APP ID. Do you know which kind of provisioning are you using to build archive your app an to share later? is that the same that you use via xcode installation? Usually for ADHOC distribution I make an archive using APPSTORE provisioning and share it with ADHOC  provisioning.

Comment: For XCode installations I set the code signing identity to my development profile. For ad-hoc distrubtions I set the code signing identity for the archive to the ad-hoc profile, then at the distrubtion part of the archive sign it again with the ad-hoc OR the push. The OR is there because sometimes one combination works sometimes the other combination works, my whole question therefore is which combination SHOULD it be and why have I observed inconsistency in which combination works and which doesn't.

Comment: The combination is the one that I've already told you: archive with appstore provisioning, distribute with ADHOC provisioning and you server should authenticate using distribution PUSH certificate to APNS. Of course you appids should match.

Comment: But I am not yet at the stage of releasing to the app store, so don't have an appstore profile. That's what ad-hoc is for - for releasing internally without using the app store. Therefore why need to create and use an appstore profile when its an ad-hoc distribution? I'm sorry if I am frustrating you but you answers are more confusing then clarifying and not stated in simple unambiguous terms.

Comment: I'm sorry..maybe someone else could clarify better. That's the procedure I know and that works, I guess that you can change the first step archiving using ad-hoc, Try...

Comment: Hey I am having this issue right now, it's confused me but I will try Andrea's suggestion. I also feel its a bit weird, although, to archive with app store profile rather than ad hoc. So I'll report on how it goes.

Comment: @Andrea Hi! I have the same problem with Piepants but your solution didn't work. When I install apps using XCode 6 the Push Notification is working but when apps are installed via iTunes using ADHOC Automatic Provisioning Profile the Push Notification is not working. Any updates or other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: ADHOC means ADHoc provisioning and Production certificates